# How to check for file contents in another file c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, file, io

I know Basics of Read and Write file using StreamReader No idea about compare!!

[image]

As You can see in above Image I've two files Error file and archive file.. I need to compare
the 2nd column based on position which from (9 to 11) for e.g. (111) is at 9 positon in text file with 2nd column in archive file at same position(9 to 11) in text file.

If code from error file is there in archive file then copy the entire record to New File.

I need to perform this activity using C#?

> Edit : Fles are .txt but separator isn't same no. of tabs sometimes it
>   2 or 3 But position are fixed 9 to 11 now, but it could change in
>   future like 14 to 16.

Comment: What have you done by now? if none, you should get all lines of your file and loop them, read this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalllines

Comment: So are these files only .txt files and the separator of the columns is a tab?

Comment: Files are .txt but separator isn't same no. of tabs sometimes it 2 or 3 But position are fixed 9 to 11 now, but it could change in future like 14 to 16.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient and concise approach which should work if the format is strict:

```
var positions1 = new[] { 9, 10, 11 };
var positions2 = new[] { 14, 15, 16 };
var f1Lines = File.ReadLines(path1)
    .Select((l, i) => new { Line = l, Cols = l.Split('\t'), Num = i + 1 })
    .Where(x => x.Cols.Length >= 2);
var f2Lines = File.ReadLines(path2)
    .Select((l, i) => new { Line = l, Cols = l.Split('\t'), Num = i + 1 })
    .Where(x => x.Cols.Length >= 2);
var toBeArchived = from i in positions1
                   join f1 in f1Lines on i equals f1.Num
                   join f2 in f2Lines on f1.Cols[1] equals f2.Cols[1]
                   where positions2.Contains(f2.Num)
                   select new { f1, f2 };
foreach (var toArchive in toBeArchived)
{ 
    // i'm not sure what you want to do with it finally
    // use File.WriteAllLines if you want to create the merged files
}
```

The LINQ query joins both files on the line and only the lines 9, 10 and 11 when the second columns are equal. Note that you need to add `using System.IO` and `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: I need to write matched valued rows into new file, I'm not aware of LINQ how you'll read input files here?

Comment: But in my 2nd File record isn't at 9, 10, 11 position.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: It can be in 9-11 in file1 and in line 9-11 in file2 but they don't need to be necessarily in the same line, is this correct?

Comment: In first file It has fixed position 9-11 but In second file it has fixed position (currently) 14-16 Doesn't matter same line, if found two times, I need to write two rows to new file.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: Edited my answer. Note that the new approach is more error-prone. I have omitted the check for columns-count.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: Sorry, i have mistakenly forgotten to add half of the code(copy/paste issue). Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm getting Index Out of Bound exception near `f2.Cols[1]`.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer: Maybe because the lines in your second doesn't contain 2 columns. That is what i've said above. Since i assumed that the format is strict i have removed the check for the column-count. Edited my answer to add the `Where`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25288/discussion-between-viswanathan-iyer-and-tim-schmelter)